# Select data between dates from oracle (date type)

Tags: java, oracle, date, jpa

I have this data in my DB and I want only select between days (not inclusive. From this data, only want extrac from day 14.

```
ID          REFERENCE       REQUEST_DATE (TYPE DATE)
2141777690  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141777750  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141777810  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141777870  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141777930  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141778080  1500541052868   14/04/18
2141778470  1500541052868   13/04/18
2141778590  1500541052868   13/04/18
2141778980  1500541052868   13/04/18
2141779010  1500541052868   13/04/18
2141779100  1500541052868   13/04/18
```

I tried this (11 results):

```
select count(entitypoll0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from MY_TABLE entitypoll0_
where entitypoll0_.POLL_ID=1500541052868 
and entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE > TO_DATE('2018-04-13','YYYY-MM-DD') 
and entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE < TO_DATE('2018-04-15','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I tried this (11 results):

```
select count(entitypoll0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from MY_TABLE entitypoll0_
where entitypoll0_.POLL_ID=1500541052868 
and (entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE between TO_DATE('2018-04-13','YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE('2018-04-15','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

By the way, I only have 5 results on the day 14, what I making wrong? I are not saving the time and I thought that this should be enough for this type of query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I are not saving the time"

Are you sure? The most obvious explanation is that the values of `REQUEST_DATE` contain a time element. You can check this quite easily by truncating the column which removes the time element. This should give uou the result you expect.

```
select count(entitypoll0_.ID) as col_0_0_ 
from MY_TABLE entitypoll0_
where entitypoll0_.POLL_ID=1500541052868 
and trunc(entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE) > TO_DATE('2018-04-13','YYYY-MM-DD') 
and trunc(entitypoll0_.REQUEST_DATE) < TO_DATE('2018-04-15','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

---

> " I was assuming that using Date type (instead of timestamp, etc..) would give me the date data without time"

Oracle's DATE datetype is actually a datetime, which confuses many people new to the database. TIMESTAMP is more precise (fractional seconds) and supports timezones.

Comment: Thanks @APC, I was assuming that using Date type (instead of timestamp, etc..) would give me the date data without time :)

Comment: I'm guessing the second one (`request_date < literal`) is the one that makes the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> From this data, only want extract from day 14.

Just use `AND REQUEST_DATE >= DATE '2018-04-14' and REQUEST_DATE < DATE '2018-04-14' + 1`

it should be fine.